# I have a problem with a for. How can I loop through the for and add the data to a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have this dataframe (compressed):

```
year    month      name

2000    January    car
2000    January    bike
2000    February   train
2000    May        car
2001    January    bike
2001    February   car
2001    February   bike
2001    July       car
2002    January    car
2002    February   train
2002    March      bike
2002    July       car
```

I need to add the data for 2001 and February to a list, for this I have made the following code.

```
name2001 = []
for year in df['year']:
    if year == 2001:
        for month in df['month']:
            if month == 'February':
                for name in df['name']:
                    name2001.append(name)
```

I was debugging and I got this error:

```
'Too large to show contents. Max items to show: 300'
```

I changed it to 10000 and I get this error:

```
'Too large to show contents. Max items to show: 10000'
```

But I know that approximately 5000 data must be added.

What is wrong with the for-loop?

Comment: Do you want to add a row to your dataframe?

Comment: I need to add the names to that list 'name2001' to later work with that list with matplotlib. I don't know if it can be done.

Comment: So you want to create a list with the name2001 column, is that correct?

Comment: Oh, the data from the name2001 column, which has corresponding year value 2001 & month value February?

Comment: Yes, and I only get the names of the year 2001 and month February (in the example it would be car a bike). It would be the second question.

Comment: Added an answer based on this, hope it helps.

Comment: (I don't know what is wrong with the for loop but it is inadvisable to use for loops with dataframes anyway, so I would recommend not to.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do, for example:

```
df[df.year.eq(2001) & df.month.str.contains('February')].name
```

which will give you the contents of column `name`, which have 2001 in their `year` column and February in their `month` column.

If want a list:

```
df[df.year.eq(2001) & df.month.str.contains('February')].name.to_list()
```

giving you:

```
['car', 'bike']
```